# iOS curl -X POST integration in swift

Tags: ios, swift, curl

Hi I want to integrate the Curl POST api in my code I don't have any idea about this could any please guide me how to integrate this in swift language

The below web service call I have integrate in my code, Have tried but didn't get the result

curl -X POST http://stf.rortechnologies.com/api/session.js --data '{"user": {"email":"XXXXXX", "password":"XXXXXX"}}'  -H "Content-Type:application/json"

```
    let parameters = ["email":"admin.test@stf.com", "password":"password"]

    let header = ["user": parameters]
    //create the url with URL
    let url = URL(string: "http://stf.rortechnologies.com/api/session.js")! //change the url

    //create the session object
    let session = URLSession.shared

    //now create the URLRequest object using the url object
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: header, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }

        do {
            //create json object from data
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                print(json)
                // handle json...
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
```

here am getting the null response

Comment: Use an HTTP library for Swift?

Comment: am trying to achieve this in a native code without using any third party library

Answer (score 0):

**App Transport Security (ATS)**

You are calling a http url and not a https url. In production always https should be used. This is enforced by iOS.

For testing purposes one can declare exceptions in the info.plist, the documentation can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33

**JSON Encoding/Decoding**

In Swift there is a convenient way to encode/decode JSON with JSONEncode/JSONDecoder. A simple solution might look like the one below.

**Define Parameter Structs**

```
struct Login: Encodable {
    let user: User
}

struct User: Encodable {
    let email: String
    let password: String
}
```

**Define Return Struct**

```
struct Result: Decodable {
    //add expected JSON fields here
}
```

**Rest Call**

```
private func makeRestCall() {

    let login = Login(user: User(email: "admin.test@stf.com", password: "password"))
    guard let loginJson = try? JSONEncoder().encode(login) else { return }

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    guard let url = URL(string: "<add some valid url here>") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = loginJson

    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                guard let data = data else {
                    print ("call failed - no data returned")
                    return
                }
                guard let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data) else {
                    print ("json decoding failed")
                    return
                }
                print ("call succesfully returned \(result)")
            } else {
                print ("call failed with status \(response.statusCode)")
            }
        } else {
            print ("call failed: no http response")
        }
    }

    dataTask.resume()

}
```

**Check in a HTTPS Proxy**

To make sure that you send the correct data, you could use a HTTPS proxy software. There it would look like this:

[image: check in proxy]

Comment: Thanks you very much for your reply,  And have tried the same that you suggested

Comment: getting finished with error - code: -1001, TTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89]) errors

Comment: Have enabled the App Transport Security Settings -> Allow Arbitrary Loads is YES

Comment: Could you tell me what I missed out

Comment: In NSURLError.h you can find all NSURL-related error codes: there is -1001 defined as NSURLErrorTimedOut. So the app makes a call, but there is no server response. So probably a server problem.

Comment: Do you get a response if you use your curl request from the command line?

Comment: Yes I have:,  curl -X POST http://stf.rortechnologies.com/api/session.js --data '{"user": {"email":"admin@stf.com", "password":"AlumniPortal@123$"}}'  -H "Content-Type:application/json"

SAMPLE RESPONSE:
{
  "token": "a87e601e83b2d450cc6aef288d03377e",
  "user": {
    "id": 117,
    "email": "admin@stf.com",
    "name": "Jassem al balooshi",
    "phone_number": "345923122",
    "major": "MBA",
    "passedout": "2006-2008",
    "company": null,
    "description": null,
}}

Comment: Interesting. When I try your curl request, there is a timeout. Could it be that your computer is on a different network than your iPhone?

Comment: Yes I too get the timeout exception, actually am checking with this in a simulator.

Comment: I get the exception also with the curl command line call:
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to stf.rortechnologies.com port 80: Operation timed out`

Comment: Oh then would be the issue from the server side. can u please check this url in the curl comment line  http://members.sharjahcd.ae/session.js

Comment: that is actually the production url

Comment: no timeout any longer, but gives a http status code 404 ('not found'), on both, the command line and on iOS

Comment: okay very thanks for your time and help, Let me check with the server side.